# Liferay portlet deployment - class cast exception

Tags: java, jsf-2, portlet, classcastexception

I am new to portlets and I am trying to build one from my JSF 2.0 app. I am using liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.0-ce-b4, JSF 2.1.3 and PortletFaces bridge 2.0.1.

When I try to install the portlet into liferay, I allways get the following exception and I really dont know why, because according to the documentation, the org.portletfaces.bridge.GenericFacesPortlet shoult implement portlet interface...

> 09:31:31,709 ERROR [HotDeployUtil:114]
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotD eployException: Error
>   registering portlets for MondisVisualizer-1.3-SNAPSHOT
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error
>   registering portl ets for MondisVisualizer-1.3-SNAPSHOT
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.BaseHotDeployListener.throwHotDe
>   ployException(BaseHotDeployListener.java:46)
>           at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(P
>   ortletHotDeployListener.java:117)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil._doFireDeployEvent
>   (HotDeployUtil.java:111)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil._fireDeployEvent(H
>   otDeployUtil.java:188)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(Ho
>   tDeployUtil.java:40)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletContextListener.doPortalInit
>   (PortletContextListener.java:101)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePor
>   talLifecycle.java:42)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLif
>   ecycleUtil.java:61)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLif
>   ecycleUtil.java:53)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLife
>   cycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:50)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletContextListener.contextIniti
>   alized(PortletContextListener.java:55)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContex
>   t.java:4723)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:
>   5226)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:
>   5221)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExec
>   utor.java:886)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
>   .java:908)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) **Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.portletfaces.bridge.GenericFacesPor
>   tlet cannot be cast to javax.portlet.Portlet**
>           at com.liferay.portlet.PortletBagFactory.create(PortletBagFactory.java:1
>   31)
>           at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.initPortlet(Po
>   rtletHotDeployListener.java:603)
>           at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy
>   (PortletHotDeployListener.java:385)
>           at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(P
>   ortletHotDeployListener.java:114)
>           ... 17 more

portlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<portlet-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd">
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>Visualizer</portlet-name>
        <portlet-class>org.portletfaces.bridge.GenericFacesPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view</name>
            <value>/index.xhtml</value>
        </init-param>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
        </supports>
        <portlet-info>
            <title>Mondis Visualizer</title>
        </portlet-info>
    </portlet>
</portlet-app>
```

liferay-portlet.xml:

```
<liferay-portlet-app>
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>Visualizer</portlet-name>
        <instanceable>true</instanceable>
        <remoteable>false</remoteable>
        <ajaxable>false</ajaxable>
        <!-- <header-portlet-css>/resources/styles/bookCatalog.css</header-portlet-css>
        <header-portlet-javascript>/resources/scripts/jsf.js</header-portlet-javascript> -->
    </portlet>
</liferay-portlet-app>
```

liferay-display.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE display PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Display 6.0.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-display_6_0_0.dtd">

 <display>
    <category name="category.mondis.visualizer">
        <portlet id="Visualizer" />
    </category>
 </display>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the issue, which kills my portlet.

The porlet.jar of the bundled liferay is probably somehow hacked/modified. The workaround is to set portlet.jar dependency as "provided" in maven - and java will link your code at run-time to the (probably modified) library in tomcat. And it will work...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: If you are using Tomcat (and possibly others) this is actually because the exact same classes are loaded by different ClassLoader's.  Tomcat uses a hierarchy of ClassLoader's and Liferay places portlet.jar in tomcats lib/ext folder which means Liferay will find the portlet interfaces there.  But when you have portlet.jar in your own classpath as well, your app will find it there instead.  When the exact same class is loaded by different ClassLoader's, they are truely different class objects so you will end up getting this ClassCastException.

Answer (score 1):

Go to
liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\webapps

There you will find the file which you are trying to deploy, 
Also:

D ...... \liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\temp
Temp will create a folder of what you have deployed in the deployed folder. I suggest to delete all the content in temp and restart your server.

Comment: go to

liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\webapps,

and you will find the files, that you need to delete them, so delete them and hier also

D ...... \liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\temp.

and you can delete the files that you want.

Start Server agein, and try : it has worked with me .